# search data and will choose to display in static table. like an add to cart

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display data after in static table just like an "Add to Cart".

```
 <table>
    <th>Item</th> <th>Description</th>       

    <tr>
    <td>Monitor<td>
    <td>Monitor Blue<td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Mouse<td>
    <td>Mouse Wireless<td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Keyboard<td>
    <td>Keyboard<td>
    </tr>
```

My search form : This is no problem is searching item. Only in the add button every row. So when you search for item you have choice if you want to add in static table.

Search:

Mysql when search

```
    <?
    $sql = "select * from item_tb where name='".$search."'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);     

    echo "     
<table cellspacing='20' border='0' ><tr> <th>Item</th><th>Description</th>
</tr>";    

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      

        echo "     
<tr> <td>    
".$row["name"]."</td> <td>    
".$row["description"]."</td>";


echo" <form name='add' method='POST'>";
echo" <td><a href='item.php?id=".$row['Iid']."'><input type='submit' value='Add'></td></a>";
echo" </form>";    
}    
    }    
 ?>
```

Here is my main problem. i don't how to make table where i'll get the data i have search and will display as many as item i add. I'm really down in this.

```
 <?
                if($id != "") 
                    {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_tb WHERE Iid='".$id."'";
                $result=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo" ".$row["name"]." ";
            }
         }

            }
                ?>
```

Comment: Your question description is confusing,Can you say it in simple words without involving talking about your code???

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai , there you go. im sorry if i make you confuse

Comment: What do you mean by that??

Comment: hmm . im trying to get data after search and display in static table. like an add to card. get as many as you want.

Comment: You mean you want to search for items and then you want to show matches,That's it right??

Comment: No, i have to problem with search. coz my code works in search and display item. the problem is, after search i want to get the data i have search and display again in table. like your ordering item.

Comment: A live link to your search page would be great..!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if($id != "") {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_tb WHERE Iid='" . $id . "'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    } 
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: .its working , but when i search another item and then add. it will just replace the first one. not storing multiple item in table.

Comment: how about this? just change in the while part

Comment: what the error said? i thought the error part in while? if yes ($result) become ($result)) its just missing 1 )

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given